# How to order rows by associated tables?

Tags: sql

I have to tables `teams` and `payments`, which one team have many payments:

```
payments:
  team_id reference teams.id
```

Now I want a query to get all teams ordered by count(payments), how to?

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result with appropriate DBMS tag.

Answer (score 0):

Most of DBMS has support `fetch first` clause, so you can do :

```
select team_id, count(payments)
from payments p
group by team_id
order by count(payments) desc
fetch first 1 rows only;
```

If you want `team_name` then you can do `JOIN` :

```
select t.id as team_id, t.name, count(p.payments)
from teams t join
     payments p
     on p.team_id = t.id
group by t.id, t.name
order by count(p.payments) desc
fetch first 1 rows only;
```

Comment: Save some typing and do order by a column alias.

Comment: @jarlh - The query as written will work in any SQL-based RDBMS I can think of.  The modification you propose will only work in some.  Without knowing the target DBMS, the answer is better as it is.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger, which dbms doesn't support order by column alias?!? (But still supporting FETCH FIRST...)

Answer (score 0):

I guess op needs team name also

```
  select p.team_id,t.name as team_name, count(payments) as Number_of_payment
    from payments p
    inner join team t
    on p.team_id=t.team_id
    group by p.team_id,t.name
    order by count(payments) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.id, count(*)
FROM team t
JOIN payments p ON t.id = p.team_id
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use a subquery to keep it neat and readable

```
WITH count_payments AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) as count_of_payments,
           team_id
    FROM payments
    GROUP BY team_id
)
SELECT count_payments.count_of_payments,
       count_payments.team_id,
       teams.* --Replace * with what fields you want
FROM count_payments
INNER JOIN teams on teams.team_id = count_payments.team_id
ORDER BY count_payments.count_of_payments
```